# systemd run fossil as non-root user

Tags: systemd, non-root-user

I want to run fossil as systemd service under non-root user.

```
useradd  -r fossil

touch /etc/systemd/system/fossil.service
```

fossil.service file:

```
[Unit]
User=fossil
Group=fossil
Description=Fossil Service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
 
[Service]
Type=simple
User=fossil
Group=fossil
WorkingDirectory=/opt/fossil/repos
ExecStart=/usr/bin/fossil server --localhost  --port 9000 --repolist  /opt/fossil/repos
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Fossil user/group is an owner of /opt/fossil directory.

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl stop fossil
sudo systemctl start fossil
sudo systemctl status fossil -l
```

Output:

```
fossil.service - Fossil Service
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/fossil.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-09-26 17:59:10 CEST; 1s ago
      Process: 2015 ExecStart=/usr/bin/fossil server --localhost --port 9000 --repolist /opt/fossil/repos (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
     Main PID: 2015 (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
```

`sudo journalctl -u fossil`

Print output:

```
.... systemd[12954]: fossil.service: Changing to the requested working directory failed: Permission denied
Sep 27 systemd[12954]: fossil.service: Failed at step CHDIR spawning /usr/bin/fossil: Permission denied
Sep 27 systemd[1]: fossil.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Sep 27 systemd[1]: fossil.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 27 systemd[1]: fossil.service: Service RestartSec=3s expired, scheduling restart.
Sep 27 systemd[1]: fossil.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Sep 27 systemd[1]: Stopped Fossil Service.
Sep 27 systemd[1]: Started Fossil Service.
```

```
ls -all /opt/fossil
drwxr-xr-x 4 fossil fossil 4096 Sep 27 repos
```

If I remove line

```
User=fossil
```

Everything work fine.

How can I fossil as fossil user

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139498/discussion-on-question-by-anton-prokofiev-systemd-run-fossil-as-non-root-user).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about `fossil`, but your problem is clearly related to permissions.

If you ever ran `sudo fossil ... /opt/fossil/repos`, then it is possible that you now have a file in that directory which is owned by `root` and not world-writable.

A catch-all solution would be:

```
sudo chown -R fossil:fossil /opt/fossil
```

A slightly more targeted approach would be

```
sudo chown -R fossil:fossil /opt/fossil/repos
```

This will recursively change ownership of all files/directories it needs to `fossil`.

This is usually safe to do in `/opt/<package>/` because `/opt` usually contains relocatable packages which are not dependencies of other packages and contents which are intended to be run in their own little world anyways.

I am even more comfortable with this because the binary `/usr/bin/fossil` is not in `/opt` and so `fossil` will not be able to overwrite itself.

But it's good to offer as narrow of permissions as possible.  So see what's in `/opt/fossil`.  If it is split up into the traditional `bin/`, `etc/`, `lib/`, `var/`, then do this on `var/` only. If it has configuration files that it should not touch itself, then ensure those are not owned by `fossil`.  If it clearly has a read-write data directory, like `/opt/fossil/repos`, then `chown` that directory only.